# How to handle multiple subscriptions in signle checkout? How to handle stripe webhook event?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, subscription

For context I'm implementing the same billing interval subscriptions in one checkout

As far as I've understood, I've added multiple `line_items` with their price_ids and quantity and all checkout is working fine.
But I'm not able to handle the webhook events for this kinda multiple subscriptions checkout.

When we do single subscription checkout we get the subscription data in checkout.session.complete event object.

How can we get the all the subscriptions data from this object. So that for all subscriotions we can loop through this array and create a record in our DB.

```ruby
def handle_checkout_session_completed(event)
  puts "checkout.session.completed\n"
  return unless User.exists?(event.data.object.client_reference_id)

  checkout_session = event.data.object
  puts "checkout_session: #{checkout_session}\n"

  session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.retrieve({
    id: checkout_session['id'],
    expand: ['line_items']
  })

  line_items = session.line_items.data
  puts line_items

  if checkout_session.payment_status == 'paid'
    fulfill_order(checkout_session, line_items)
  end
end

def fulfill_order(checkout_session, line_items)
  user = User.find(checkout_session.client_reference_id)
  user.update(stripe_id: checkout_session.customer)

  line_items.each do |line_item|
    product_id = line_item.price.product
    tool_id = determine_tool_id(product_id)

    Subscription.create(
      user: user,
      subscription_id: checkout_session.subscription,
      plan_id: tool_id,
      interval: line_item.price.recurring.interval,
      status: 'active',
      current_period_start: Time.at(checkout_session.subscription.current_period_start).to_datetime,
      current_period_end: Time.at(checkout_session.subscription.current_period_end).to_datetime
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```ruby
when 'invoice.payment.succeeded'
      puts "invoice.payment.succeeded\n"
      return unless event.data.object.subscription.present?

      stripe_subscriptions = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve(event.data.object.subscription)
      subscriptions_items = stripe_subscriptions.items.data
      # find all the subscriptions associate with the stripe subscription

      subscriptions_items.each do |subscription_item|
        subscription = Subscription.find_by(subscription_item_id: subscription_item.id)
        subscription.update(
          status: stripe_subscriptions.status,
          current_period_start: Time.at(stripe_subscriptions.current_period_start).to_datetime,
          current_period_end: Time.at(stripe_subscriptions.current_period_end).to_datetime,
          interval: subscription_item.price.recurring.interval
        )
      end
```

Basically we have to listen for the `invoice.payment.succeeded` event which returns the object which has included the subscription id. And we can retrieve the subscriptions using following line `stripe_subscriptions = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve(event.data.object.subscription)`

And we can for_each the each sub-subscription that user has subscribed to and save in our database.

Answer (score 0):

One `subscription` mode CheckoutSession can only create one subscription, there's no way to create multiple subscriptions with one CheckoutSession.

Comment: Nah. It is possible to create multiple subscriptions in a single checkout. Somehow after going through Stripe documentation, I made it work.

Comment: Do you mind to share how you make it work?

Comment: sure. Basically I've to go skim through the stripe docs and search for subscription object returns after successful payment. And in the that object we have sub- subscriptions included in it

Comment: I see. I'm glad that works for you! I believe what you refer to is the subscription item, and yes you can have multiple subscription items in one subscription.